# Convert SQL to JPA Specifications

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm getting a paginated list of `product_order` using simple `CrudRepository` with JPA Specification. The problem is building query dynamically with some filters, among other things is product type (not-simple product is produced by at least 3 steps)
My SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM product_order po 
WHERE product_id IN
(
SELECT t.product_id FROM
    (SELECT pp.product_id, count(1) AS cnt FROM product_process pp WHERE pp.version=po.pp_version GROUP BY pp.product_id) t
WHERE t.cnt > 3
)
```

the `count()` function is used as a column in a temporary table. So my question is how to use aggregate functions in temporary table

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you really want, but you can rewrite your query

```
SELECT *
FROM product_order po 
WHERE EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM product_process pp
  WHERE pp.product_id = po.product_id AND pp.version = po.pp_version
  HAVING count(1) > 3
)
```

It should be easy to make this work with Spring Data JPA Specifications